# How to insert into table select function query with Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Insert into table When a table with a function result value is selected, the value does not appear. What should I do?

- Function query result

  ```
  hive> SELECT start_num,geoip(start_ip,'COUNTRY_CODE','/usr/local/hive/lib/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb') from geoip limit 3;
  OK
  17/05/24 18:02:15 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
  16778240        AU
  16779264        CN
  16781312        JP
  Time taken: 0.129 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
  ```
- When you insert function query query results

  ```
  Query insert into table iptest2 SELECT start_num,geoip(start_ip,'COUNTRY_CODE','/usr/local/hive/lib/GeoLite2-Country.mmdb') from geoip limit3;

  17/05/24 18:05:41 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 2
  16778240
  16779264
  16781312
  Time taken: 0.115 seconds, Fetched: 3 row(s)
  ```
- iptest2 table desc

  ```
  hive> desc iptest2;
  OK
  17/05/25 09:26:28 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input files to process : 1
  code                    string
  ccode                   string
  Time taken: 0.066 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
  ```

  )

  - GEOIP function UDF (Use the UDF function from the link below)

https://github.com/Spuul/hive-udfs/blob/master/src/main/java/com/spuul/hive/GeoIP2.java

Comment: How many columns in table `iptest2` ?

Comment: The minimum for this kind of question is to add the table definition and the UDF interface